# Swap item animation in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

In my ListView, when I click on an Item, I want to sort it at the end of list, while the rest of the list should fill the gap by scrolling up. I have managed it to animate the item going down to the end with this code:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_goal_content, null);
        }

    ...
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (animationRunning) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // only animate if item is not already at the end of list.
                    if (goals.indexOf(goal) != goals.size() - 1) {
                        int path = (getCount() - position) * animview.getHeight();

                        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, path);
                        animation.setDuration(700);


                        animation.setZAdjustment(Animation.ZORDER_TOP);
                        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                                animationRunning = true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                animationRunning = false; 
                                // simply remove from its position and append to end 
                                goals.remove(goal);
                                goals.add(goal);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {                        }
                        });
                        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

But I have no idea how to scroll items up to fill the gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to rebuild my List and use a RecyclerView. It contains a build-in ItemAnimator. Instead of starting an own animation like in the code in my question, I simply used this to swap the items:

```
// get position of the item to be moved
int indexOf = goals.indexOf(goal);
goals.remove(goal); // remove from its position
goals.add(goal);    // add to end of list
// Notify view about the move: it will handle the animation itself :)
notifyItemMoved(indexOf, goals.size()-1);
```

It took a few hours to rebuild my code but now I am glad not to stuck on a Listview.